# Method Prerequisites

Tags: c#, asynchronous, aop, restsharp, postsharp

**The Situation**

I'm working on a OAuth2 Api Wrapper. Some api routes are for logged people and some for anonymous and logged.

Here is an example of one method in my wrapper :

```
public async Task<UploadListResponse> List(bool pagination = false, int page = 1, int limit = 10)
    {
        var request = UploadRequests.List(pagination, page, limit);

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var restResponse = await Context.Client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        return restResponse.Handle<UploadListResponse>();
    }
```

I build a request with all parameter set up then execute the request and then handle the answer in case I have an api error and then output an object containing all the data that request gave me.

**The problem**

With OAuth2, when you log to the API you'll receive an access token and a refresh token. If your access token is expired you have to contact the api with your refresh token to get a fresh new access token.

As I said earlier some of my method needs you to be logged but if your access token is expired I want to try to refresh token before throwing an exception like with this method :

```
public async Task<bool> NeedRelog()
    {
        try
        {
            var validAuth = await ValidAuth();
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                var refresh = await Refresh(Context.Client.Config.RefreshToken);
            }
            catch
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

ValidAuth check with the API if you are logged and if I have an exception then I'll try to refreshToken.

I want to tag method that need logged to call NeedRelog() and those who aren't tag to not call it.

I may just do it in every method but it wouldn't be clean.

**What I've done so far**

I've found a great tool : PostSharp that seems to fit my needs.

I've started to do a checkLog aspect like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class CheckLog : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IOnStateMachineBoundaryAspect
{
    public CheckLog()
    {
        ApplyToStateMachine = false;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var instance = (ApiService)args.Instance;
        var res = instance.Parent.OAuth.NeedRelog().Result;

        if (!res)
        {
            args.Exception = new Exception("Need to relog");
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Where I'm stuck**

The Main problem is with the call to my NeedRelog() Method. Due to the fact this is an async method I'm struggling to make my aspect await for it.

- If my OnEntry method is async then It won't block the call if you are not logged.
- If my OnEntry method is not async and I wait for needLog it freeze and nothing happen.

I really want to know to use this kind of "conditional method call" with postsharp, it looks awesome but the fact is after looking for hours in the documentation I didn't find a way to do what I want.

I'm starting to ask myself if it is even possible to achieve what I'm aiming to do.

Comment: Did you try using a way to make the call synchronous maybe with something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/3131696 ?

Comment: It works like a charm ty for this code snippets that helped me understand how async can be synced. ty sir !

Comment: Glad that helped you @Sebastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you try using a way to make the call synchronous maybe with something like this [stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/3131696](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/3131696) ? – M22an 5 hours ago

As I can't mark a comment as answering a question I quote your comment to make this question answered as it is said here : [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Thanks you for this M22an.